# How can I convert "Mon, 23 Sep 2013 07:00:00 GMT" as a string into "2013-09-23" using STR_TO_DATE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I've got a long query with comparisons between tables, and one table has this format:

```
"Mon, 23 Sep 2013 07:00:00 GMT"
```

And another table has this format:

```
"2013-09-23"
```

How can I do a query where I can essentially do a

```
SELECT * from table1, table2
WHERE table1.date = table2.date
```

Something like this?

```
select column1, column2, DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(table2.`column2`,'%a, %d %m %Y %I:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d') as convert_date 
FROM table1, table2
```

Comment: You're saying the dates are stored as strings? AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH!!! - By the way, what have you tried? :-)

Comment: What do you mean by format? What is the datatype of two columns? If both of them are type date, you dont have to do any conversion.

Comment: @MartyMcVry. Yep, they're both strings of two different types. One refactoring coming up.

Comment: @CuriousMind. Both of them of type string. Like I said to Marty above, a nice refactoring is coming up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the two dates are in the same timezone you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    something
FROM
    longformat,
    shortformat
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(longformat.date,"%a, %d %b %Y") =
    STR_TO_DATE(shortformat.date, "%Y-%m-%d");
```

where longformat contains the date on the format `"Mon, 23 Sep 2013 07:00:00 GMT"` and shortformat contains the date on the format `"2013-09-23"`.

Comment: Worked brilliantly. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. You should consider converting your data to the date format though. =)